# React-Router passing props between main and sidebar components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm using Meteor with React-Router and I have the following code:

**Routes.jsx:**

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute components={{ main: SelectTable, sidebar: MenuBar }} />
        <Route path='/DisplayTable/:tableId'
          components={{ main: DisplayTable, sidebar: MenuBar }} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-root'));
});
```

**App.jsx:**

```
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    // if there's only one child logic here, irrelevant
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className="Main">
          {this.props.main}
        </div>
        <div className="Sidebar">
          {this.props.sidebar}
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

My **DisplayTable** component listens to a Meteor subscription to the database and eventually gets these properties:

```
DisplayTable.propTypes = {
  tableId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  rows: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  cols: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object,
};
```

And my **MenuBar** component renders this:

```
<li><InsertRow tableId={this.props.params.tableId}/></li>
```

Where **InsertRow** has these properties

```
InsertRow.propTypes = {
  rows: PropTypes.array,
  tableId: PropTypes.string,
};
```

where the row properties of both `InsertRow` and `DisplayTable` are exactly the same.

**How do I pass properties from the main component to the sidebar so I can pass it forward to the component from there?**

- Perhaps something with `React.cloneElement` though I wasn't really able to wrap my head around that one...
- I've looked at all of the properties of `main` and `sidebar`and I can't seem to find anything useful...

Work-arounds:

- I could theoretically subscribe and get the data again since I have the `tableId`, but that seems excessively stupid since these two components are literally being rendered in the same Route.
- I could also just make a fake div on the `MenuBar` and use jQuery to replace it when I'm displaying the table, but that seems very not-reacty.
- I could also just make another menu for my **DisplayTable** part of the app, but I'm trying to avoid clutter.

(I am not using react router 4.0 if that's relevant to the answer, using 3.0.5, latest version of meteor though I guess that's not relevant in this context)

Edit: I guess I will be adding the container above the path so I have the data already. Sort of makes sense though I'll leave this here in case someone has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there might be a better way to do this, I will explain below what I ended up doing:

**Routes.jsx**

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}> 
        //... like before

        <Route path='/DisplayTable' component={ Comp } >
          <Route path='/DisplayTable/:tableId'
            components={{ main: DisplayTable, sidebar: MenuBar }} />
        </Route>

      </Route>
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('react-root'));
});
```

Then I added the component layout `Comp`

**Comp.jsx**

```
class Comp extends Component {
  render() {
    // this is the final html for our table
    let displayTable = [];
    let menuBar = [];
    // while the data is loading, the html is a spinner
    if (this.props.loading) {
      displayTable.push(
        <div key='table-container' className='table-container table-container-no-data'>
          <div key='loading'>
            <span>Loading data...</span>
            <Spinner key='spinner' spinnerName='three-bounce' />
          </div>
        </div>);
    } else {
      // the Display Table properties
      displayTable = React.Children.map(this.props.main, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
        rows: this.props.rows,
        cols: this.props.cols,
      }));
      // the Menu Bar properties
      menuBar = React.Children.map(this.props.sidebar, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
        rows: this.props.rows,
        cols: this.props.cols,
      }));
    }

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className="content">
          {displayTable}
        </div>
        <div className="menu">
          {menuBar}
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

Comp.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  rows: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  cols: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  //... etc
};
/**
 * A Meteor createContainer component which retrieves data from Meteor & Mongo
 */
export default createContainer((props) => {
  // get the rows & cols by Meteor subscriptions here, as well as a loading to figure out when the subscription finished (this was originally in DisplayTable)
}
```

**DisplayTable.jsx**

```
DisplayTable.propTypes = {
  rows: PropTypes.array,
  cols: PropTypes.array,
};
```

(turns out those are all I need as opposed to above - use them throughout component but getting them from `Comp` basically)

**MenuBar.jsx**

```
MenuBar.propTypes = {
  rows: PropTypes.array,
  cols: PropTypes.array,
};
```

(same as above, use them when calling InsertRow)

MenuBar also calls `InsertRow` like so: `<li><InsertRow tableId={this.props.params.tableId} cols={this.props.cols} isDisabled={false} /></li>`